# How many 8 letter words in scrabble can be formed from the tiles used in the word PARRAMATTA?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 8 letter words in scrabble can be formed from the tiles used in the word PARRAMATTA?

Here's what I've done so far:

There are 8 'spots' to choose from, with $\frac{10!}{2!}$ possibilities (as no letter can be used more than once). However we have repeated letters (A(4),R(2) and T(2)). So we divide the above by $2!2!4!.$ But I don't seem to be getting the right answer, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Take `P M RR TT AAAA` and consider all the cases of the two letters *not* selected, by type, and the count of permutations of the rest.

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|}\hline
 \text{PM:}& \frac{8!}{2!^24!}
\\ \hline
\text{PT, PR, MT, or MR:}& 4\times\frac{8!}{2!4!}
\\ \hline
\text{TT, or RR:}& 2\times \frac{8!}{2!4!}
\\ \hline
\text{TR:}& 
\\ \hline
\text{PA or MA:}& 
\\ \hline
\text{TA or RA:}& 
\\ \hline
\text{AA:}& 
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Complete the table and add them together.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of these permutations have repeating letters. For example I can say:
PARMATAA and it will only have one “R”. You must correct for repeating letters when the chosen permutation has them.

Comment: Oh, right! So would I have to do this case by case? What would the cases be...